# pandas.styler type to exportable table and how to create a dashboard to show these tables?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

i have created a table with conditional color coding . But it is in

```
pandas.formats.style.Styler
```

format.Now i want to export it exactly same way to a webpage or a dashboard. if i am exporting using to_html() , it is not showing same as styler format.How cN i export it exactly as it is showing in pandas.formats.style.Styler format .
and what is the best way to put these tables in a dashboard . any suggestions?

Tried using bokeh but it is not taking this format as input.

Comment: Can't you use `render()`on the style object? Eg: `df.style.highlight_null().apply(highlight_max).render()`

Comment: yes! I used render()  already but it converts into html form only. not exactly how it looks in pandas style. this is the one i am using  `df3.style.apply(color,axis=1).render()` @JulienMarrec